# Codeiginiter array $data view

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I need an array from my data that I can `foreach` on the view, an array like this: `album_name,cover_image`

Here is my code:

```
function myFunction(){

    $alb = array();

    foreach($albums as $album)
    {
        //if($album[0]['count'] > 0){
        $alb[]['album_name'] = $album['name'];

        foreach($this->get_fbimages($facebook,$album['id']) as $img)
        {
            $alb[]['cover'] = $img[0]['picture'];
        }   
    }

    return $alb;
}
```

and I do `array_merge($data,myFunction());`

Comment: How can I creeate that array..that I need: `array(array('album_name' => 'name of the album','cover_image' => 'url'),array('album_name'.....)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your array is invalid, to the result you want.

Try it this way.

```
function myFunction(){

    $alb = array();

    foreach($albums as $album)
    {
        $tempArray['album_name'] = $album['name'];
        foreach($this->get_fbimages($facebook,$album['id']) as $img)
        {
            $tempArray['cover'][] = $img[0]['picture'];
        }

        $alb[] = $tempArray;

    }

    return $alb;
}
```

Comment: `$tempArray['cover'][] =` should be `$tempArray['cover'] =` otherwise `$tempArray['cover']` will be an array instead of just a url string.

Comment: @Brandon, But its inside a foreach, it is certain it will hold more values than one.

Comment: You're right. Missed that part, was going off his comment up top about his desired array output.